# Get errno 150 when restoring sql dump file

Tags: mysql, database-restore, errno

I've use MySQL Dump Distrib 5.1.45 to backup my database. It's generated a file a below:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.45, for Win32 (ia32)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: SG
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.16

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `hist`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `hist` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HistUi` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StdModel` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `StdModel` (`StdModel`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKA0015AD86A02605F` FOREIGN KEY (`StdModel`) REFERENCES `std` (`Model`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `hist` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `hist` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `hist` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `std`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `std` (
  `Model` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Owner` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Model`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

But when I try to restore from that file, I fails and show a message such as:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can’t create table ‘SG.hist’ (errno: 150)
```

I try some solutions got from Google search but not work:

- Add `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` on top of dump file
- Use mysql.exe from MySql Server 5.5
- Use MySql Workbench
- ...

I wasted too may time on this issue but still can't find the root cause leading to the problem. I cannot use newer mysqldump.exe file to create dump file again, and don't want to change database structure now. A little change in sql dump file is acceptable.

**Update:**

Bring that file to other PCs which have the same MySQL server and it works fine. I tried to compare my.ini files, even copying my.ini file from another PC doesn't make it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, which I believe was caused by tables that were expected to be created later in the same dump file already existing, perhaps with slightly different definitions.  I dropped the database and recreated it from scratch and everything worked fine.  Could this be your problem?

Comment: You got a point. I'll try it tomorrow because I don't have that PC here. Will feedback you as soon as possible